# How to execute a script on sftp connection?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I run an ssh server on my machine and I restrict access to certain users to sftp only with internal-sftp & ChrootDirectory. What I need is a way to execute a script before chrooting users. Actually, the goal is to mount an encrypted filesystem on client connection and unmount it on close.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to hack the openssh code you have to use the external sftp server. If you do it is a simple matter of putting a wrapper around it. For example: in `sshd_config`

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/local/bin/sftp-server
```

In `/usr/local/bin/sftp-server`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount_special_fs
chroot /my/secret/stuff /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
umount_special_fs
```

It *might* be possible to put a wrapper around `sshd` and launch the wrapper from `inetd` but launching `sshd` from `inted` is discouraged because it is to slow to start up.

Comment: I it possible to pass arguments to the wrapper with this method, because each user has a different filesystem ?

Comment: I quickly found the answer to me previous question in the sshd_config man, but i ran into another issue: how can I access variables such as current user and his home directory from within sshd_config ? I tried : Subsystem sftp /path/to/sftp-wrapper %u, but the wrapper receives the string %u instead of the current user name.

Comment: You can't use %u here. The script runs as the user so you can examine $USER. The approach is starting to seem a bit hackish to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pam_script, a pam module to execute script from a pam authentication module. You can add it in your pam sshd configuration.
URL: http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_script