# cygwin sftp chroot cannot view contents of bound mountpoint

Tags: ssh, mount, cygwin, chroot

I'm trying to give `user2` access only to his home directory and full permissions on `/cygdrive/e`.  I created a `Data/` directory within his `$home`, added a `bind` directive in `/etc/fstab` (see below), and issued a `mount -a`.

I've got cygwin installed and sshd running (OpenSSH_6.1p1).  When connecting with `ChrootDirectory` enabled in an sftp subsystem, `~/Data` appears to have no contents.  Even if I change the permissions for `/cygdrive/e` recursively to `0777`, the result is the same.  With `ChrootDirectory` active for that user in `sshd_config`, no contents are displayed.

However, connecting using the same user account without changing any permissions, the contents of `~/Data` is fully populated after I comment out the `Subsystem` section at the bottom of `sshd_config` and restart sshd.

So how can I grant this cat god-mode permission on `/cygdrive/e` without giving him the ability to browse any other part of the filesystem?  What am I missing?

---

The bottom of my `sshd_config` is as follows:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
Match User user2
  ChrootDirectory /home/%u
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The only line in `/etc/fstab` reads as follows:

```
/cygdrive/e /home/user2/Data none bind,posix=0,user
```

Currently, recursive ownership of `/cygdrive/e` belongs to `Administrators:Users`.  The `user2` Windows account is a member of `Users` as well as `Administrators`.  All directories have a mask of `0755`.  All files have a mask of `0644`.

I'm not crazy about `user2` having admin rights to the machine, but I'll deal with that later.  One problem at a time.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  Many elements conspire to defeat you at every turn.

#### Why not create a mountpoint within the jail?

Apparently `mount` in cygwin behaves much differently from in a POSIX operating system.  In cygwin, `mount` is limited to the scope of the current logged on session.  This means that if you mount a device as *user1*, then *user2* will not have that mount available.

It does not matter whether the mount type is `bind`, a more traditional `ntfs`-type mount, or a `cifs` network share.  No type of binding is persistent.  Even if you `mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /path/to/jail`, the sftp users won't see it -- indeed, nor would other privileged users.

[image: proof of scope of mount]

#### OK, then, why not put the jail inside /cygdrive/e?

As the sftp client connection is made, `/cygdrive/e` doesn't exist yet.  Even if it did, there's another problem.  Keep in mind that every directory from stem to stern of `/path/to/jail` must be owned by `root`.  Since `/cygdrive` is mounted at runtime for the user's session, the owner of `/cygdrive` is the current user.  And `chown root:whatever /cygdrive` does nothing -- no error, but no effect either.

#### What about a host OS solution?  Would a Windows hard link or a junction work?

Unfortunately, from the perspective of client interaction, `mklink` is just a fancy way of making shortcuts.  It doesn't matter whether you're making a file or directory symlink, a hard link, or a junction.  The sftp client sees them all as just icons with an arrow  `mklink` doesn't fool the sftp client with its particular method of trickery.

#### Accepting defeat

There's simply no way to teach an `internal-sftp` chroot to understand cygwin's awkward imitation of `mount`.  Others have tried, but even the [experts are confounded](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-05/msg00524.html).

#### Well, then, don't use internal-sftp.  Make a wrapper script to perform a mount at connect.

This might be possible.  I haven't tried it, because there [seems to be no easy way](https://serverfault.com/questions/184308/how-to-execute-a-script-on-sftp-connection) for the wrapper to differentiate privileged from chroot-jailed user, and I still want to be able to browse the full filesystem with my own account.  Besides, setting up a full chroot jail environment offends my delicate sense of aesthetic appeal.  I'd rather the logged on user have fewer places to get lost.  I prefer a low crap-to-content ratio, if that makes sense.

#### So what are you going to do?

On my Windows PC I shared the folders I want accessible to sftp.  On a small Linux appliance PC, I mapped the appropriate cifs shares via [autofs](https://superuser.com/a/583650/204705), as well as setting up [delayed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1299274&p=9873249#post9873249) `mount bind`ings in fstab, binding directories in the `autofs` mounts to mountpoints within an `internal-sftp` chroot jail.  It works smashingly!  The client connects to my Linux appliance to up/download files on my Windows shares.  For the user, the whole thing is completely transparent.  For me, the setup is tolerant of reboots and worry-free.

Perhaps this would be a good excuse for anyone in a similar situation to get a Raspberry Pi or a Plug PC of some sort and do the same.